# Lxterm -e option

Tags: redirection, xterm

I am trying to run the following command (lxterm is alias to lxterminal) 
lxterm -e "node test.js" 
it`s OK, but when test terminates the new terminal closes instantly. Can`t I make it stay until I close it?
Another question : can I do that in xterm? I was typing
xterm >&1 node
and a new xterm with > opens but I  can`t pass the .js files to node...

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found what I needed. It`s not exactly an answer to my question but it works for my desires:

```
xterm -e "node somefile.js | gvim - "
```

which actually opens the node interpret into gvim buffer, which is way better since I can save the output for benchmarks if needed.